# How can I compare two date strings with format dd/mm/yyyy in js?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to compare a "Date" type of data with an "Any" type of data, but the comparison is not working.

I'm getting the date in this code:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
var yyyy = (today.getFullYear());
today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
```

And I'm doing the comparison here:

```
for (const event of events) {
        if (event.fecha_fin >= today  && event.hora_fin > my_time) {
          console.log(event.fecha_fin > today)
          eventsWithLowestPrice.push(event.id_evento_fk)
          console.log(event.id_evento_fk)
        }
      }
```

The data type of event.fecha_fin is "Any".

I've tried to change both fecha_fin and today into "Number" data type but I don't really know how to do it.

I've tried changing the data type of "today" and "fecha_fin" to "Number" but I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: You start with `var today = new Date();` so _today_ is a `Date` object, but then you re-assign it as `today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;` so today is _now_ a `String`, not a Date at all.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking more about Typescript than JavaScript.

Comment: What is `event`? One way to compare strings with format `dd/mm/yyyy` is to parse them as dates and compare the dates. What's the expected result of `09/01/2020 >= 01/01/2022`?

Comment: @StephenP true, but then how can I compare those two types of data?

Comment: @jabaa how can I parse them as dates and then compare them? 
What is expected from that code is that if the event.fecha_fin is greater than the current date, the event show itself in the main page, ex:

Comment: Parse: `const [dd, mm, yyyy] = today.split('/'); const date = new Date(yyyy, mm - 1, dd);`. Compare: `date1 >= date2`. But what is `event`? What is `event.fecha_fin`?

Comment: @Juan — to compare you would have to turn the string back into a Date object... but I have to ask, why are you re-assigning `today` in the first place? If you want it in the mm/dd/yyyy format with the leading zeros just for _display to the user_ then save it in a different variable ... `let displayDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;` or use the Javascript [DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) method to format it without even storing it in a separate variable.

Comment: @jabaa What is expected from that code is that if the event.fecha_fin is greater than the current date, the event show itself in the main page, ex:
The date on event.fecha_fin is 05/01/2023 and the current date is 04/05/2023, so the if statement should compare both dates and then, if the date on event.fecha_fin is bigger (by bigger I mean it's not that day), then the if statement is correct and should pass to the next condition

Comment: Then you should parse both strings as dates and compare the dates. The title is misleading. `today` and `event.fecha_fin` are both strings. You are trying to compare two date strings, not a date and any.

Comment: Yes, as jabaa says you should turn `event.fecha_fin` as 05/01/2023 into a Date object, not turn `today` into a String. Comparing dates as strings _only_ works if you keep the dates in yyyy-mm-dd format, e.g. `2023-05-01` but that only works for _sorting_ — you're better off using Date objects all around, parsing strings into actual Dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the strings as dates with

```
function stringToDate(str) {
  const [dd, mm, yyyy] = str.split('/');
  return new Date(yyyy, mm - 1, dd);
}
```

and compare the dates:

```
for (const event of events) {
  const date1 = stringToDate(event.fecha_fin);
  const date2 = stringToDate(today);
  if (date1 >= date2 && event.hora_fin > my_time) {
    console.log(date1 > date2)
    eventsWithLowestPrice.push(event.id_evento_fk)
    console.log(event.id_evento_fk)
  }
}
```

Example:

```js
function stringToDate(str) {
  const [dd, mm, yyyy] = str.split('/');
  return new Date(yyyy, mm - 1, dd);
}

const events = [{fecha_fin: '01/01/2020', hora_fin: 2}];
const today = '02/02/2002';
const my_time = 1;

for (const event of events) {
  const date1 = stringToDate(event.fecha_fin);
  const date2 = stringToDate(today);
  if (date1 >= date2 && event.hora_fin > my_time) {
    console.log(date1 > date2)
    //eventsWithLowestPrice.push(event.id_evento_fk)
    console.log(event.id_evento_fk)
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to write your own `stringToDate` — just doing `new Date(event.fecha_fin)` will parse "05/01/2023" (Juan's example in the comments) into the correct Date object without having to do the manual `mm - 1` adjustment. (but have an upvote for comparing Date objects)

Comment: I erased my  first lines of code where I created "Today" and pasted your code with the new for loop but I'm getting: ReferenceError: today is not defined.

Comment: @StephenP `dd/mm/yyyy` is a non-standard format and won't work in all browsers and engines. JavaScript standard only guarantees to work with ISO date format. Some browsers provide extended support.

Comment: And if I don't erase that part, I'm getting the TypeError: str.split is not a function

Comment: @JPcoder You can't use variables that don't exist.

Comment: @jabaa true, but then when I use your code with mine, i get the TypeError: str.split is not a function.

Comment: @JPcoder I added an example. It works.

Comment: @jabaa it finally worked, thanks!